# Why does changing my state cause the error 'Maximum update depth exceeded'?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When I try to change state via the login form on my application, it gives me an error saying:

`Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

I don't see where I caused an infinite loop. Here is the `app.js` where the issue happens:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    loggedIn: false,
    token: '',
    posts: [],
    title: '',
    description: '',
    postSubmitted: false,
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  logIn = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await Axios.post(
        'http://localhost:3000/api/user/login',
        {
          email: this.state.email,
          password: this.state.password,
        },
      );
      //REACT SAYS THE ERROR OCCURS HERE!
      this.setState({
        loggedIn: true,
        token: response.data,
      });
      console.log(this.state);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.response);
    }
  };

  //other code

  render() {
    return (
      //components

      <Route path="/login">
        <Login
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
          logIn={this.logIn}
          loggedIn={this.state.loggedIn}
        />
      </Route>
    );
  }
}
```

React says the issue is coming from when I use `this.setState` to set values for `loggedIn` and `token` but I'm not sure how that is causing a loop. Here is my `LoginForm.js` file where I pass my logIn function as a prop:

```
function LoginForm(props) {
  const loggedIn = props.loggedIn;
  return loggedIn ? (
    <Redirect to={'/'} />
  ) : (
    <div className="login-cont">
      <h1>Log In</h1>
      <label> Email adress</label>
      <br />
      <input
        type="text"
        id="email"
        name="email"
        placeholder="John@email.com"
        onChange={props.handleChange}
      />
      <br />
      <label> Password</label>
      <br />
      <input
        type="text"
        id="password"
        name="password"
        placeholder="Password"
        onChange={props.handleChange}
      />
      <br />
      <input type="submit" onClick={props.logIn} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Where did I go wrong? Is it an issue with how I passed the functions as props?

Comment: Don't see anything in the given code that would do it. What else happens when you change `loggedIn/token`? Do you have any lifecycle methods like `componentDidUpdate`? Are you calling any functions in the render?

Comment: When I change `loggedin` to true, it redirects from the login page to the hom page. I dont have `componentDidUpdate` and im not calling any functions in the render lifecycle method.

Comment: Can you try distilling this down into a reproducible example in a *running* codesandbox?

Answer (score 0):

That error happens when a loop or repeatedly set state uses into `componentWillUpdate` or `componentDidUpdate`.React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

i suggest you try these two ways,
first instead of using `async` ,  use `.then().catch` ,  and in your `then` do your set state. [here you can see examples](https://medium.com/@lucymarmitchell/using-then-catch-finally-to-handle-errors-in-javascript-promises-6de92bce3afc)

or alternatively, put an `if statement` after your `try` and say if you had a user in response, do the set state.